# How do I update dictionary values that are within a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to update all final date values that are contained in a dictionary within a list with a new timestamp format.

```
new = [{'final date': '01 Aug 2001', 'number': '4733827'}, {'final date': '10 Sep 1996', 'number': '4352529'}]

for i in new:
    datetime.datetime.strptime(new['final date'], "%d %b %Y").strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z'
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-03fc4d90261f> in <module>
      2 
      3 for i in new:
----> 4     datetime.datetime.strptime(new['final date'], "%d %b %Y").strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z'
      5 
      6 

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: just do i["final_date"], because when you loop over new i represents a dictionnary

Comment: I'm partly confused. Can you add the desired output? Though as it sits your error is because you are using `new` inside your `for` loop instead of `i`.

Comment: It should be new[i['final date']] because final date is a key in a dictionary i which is inside new

Comment: Thanks - all sorted now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
new = [{'final date': '01 Aug 2001', 'number': '4733827'}, {'final date': '10 Sep 1996', 'number': '4352529'}]

for i in range(0,len(new)):
    new[i]['final date']=datetime.datetime.strptime(new[i]['final date'], "%d %b %Y").strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z'
```